# Page not found when trying to link to files in child theme directory

Tags: 404-error, wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, directory

I'm trying to create a child theme based on Toolbox 1.4 by Automattic.

I have my scripts file saved as `child_theme/js/scripts.js` on my server and I enqueue it by using

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery') );
```

in the `header.php`.

When I view source in Firefox, I see the href to the stylesheet as

```
http://example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child_theme/style.css
```

and the href to the scripts as

```
http://example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child_theme/js/scripts.js?ver=3.3.2
```

When I click on both, I can see the source of my `style.css`, but it says "Page not found" for my `scripts.js`.

I've never created a child theme before. I used to just copy a theme and modify it. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

It works when I move `scripts.js` out of the `/js/` subdirectory into the child theme's root directory and change the `wp_enequeue_script`. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be enqueuing that in functions.php instead?

```
function script_enqueueing() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'scripts',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_enqueueing');
```

Edit to add: if calling directly in header.php, use `get_template_directory_uri();` instead.

Comment: You may be right about putting it in the functions.php, but I still get 404 if the scripts.js is in a subdirectory.

Comment: Actually I don't know what the deal with the problem is. I just keep reloading the page and now it works. =/

Comment: When you change theme files at all, make sure you're flushing your cache (and emptying your W3 cache if you're using it).  On Windows it's generally CTRL+F5 instead of just F5, or on Chrome/Firefox start a private/incognito session to make sure you're not seeing old content.  I'm glad it's working though!